# React JS : Module Build Failuer, error showing in render colon

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error like this
Module build failed: SyntaxError
It gives me error in colon of render function

Here it is my code :

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry : './main.js',
output : {
    path : './',
    filename : 'index.js'
},
devServer : {
    inline : true,
    port : 3333
},
module : {
    loaders : [
        {
            test : /\.js$/,
            exclude : /node_modules/,
            loader : 'babel',
            query :{
                presets : ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2"
  }
```

main.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

var Heading = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return <th>{this.props.heading}</th>;
    }
});

var Headings = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        var headings = this.props.headings.map(function(heading) {
            return(<Heading heading = {name}/>);
        });
        return (<thead><tr>{headings}</tr><thead>);
    }
});

var Row = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return  (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.changeSet.when}</td>
                <td>{this.props.changeSet.who}</td>
                <td>{this.props.changeSet.description}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});

var Rows = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        var rows = this.props.changeSets.map(function(changeSet) {
            return(<Row changeSet = {changeSet} />);
        });
        return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return  (
            <table className='table'>
                <Headings headings={this.props.headings} />
                <Rows changeSets={this.props.changeSets} />
            </table>
        );
    }
});


/* Data Declaration */
var data = [
    { 
        "when": "2 minutes ago",
        "who": "Jill Dupre",
        "description": "Created new account"
    },
    {
        "when": "1 hour ago",
        "who": "Lose White",
        "description": "Added fist chapter"
    },
    {
        "when": "2 hours ago",
        "who": "Jordan Whash",
        "description": "Created new account"
    }
];
var headings = ['When','Who', 'Description'];

/* Call to Render Function for entire app */
ReactDom.render(<App headings={headings} changeSets={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Can somebody please provide a solution for it. I have included babel-core also but can't figure out what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error you get? which `render()` method failed? Is there an error trace?

Comment: I have uploaded an image of link. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setting up your code locally and was able to resolve the issue.

1. I was getting a `Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] - path to file` error

The reason is, The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.So remove the `babel` dependency from both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, move the `babel-loader` to your `dependencies` and clear the `devDependencies` of your `package.json` file and reinstall your modules. It should work

There are some syntax errors on
 
line 20  `render : function(){`

unclosed tags in line 15 `return (<thead><tr>{headings}</tr><thead>);`